# Что означает слово "эпинальный"?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, семантика, прилагательные

Наткнулся на такой текст:

*Его горделивая поза словно свидетельствовала о том, что он сошёл прямиком с **эпинальных** полотен художников Возрождения.*

Не могу найти значение слова "эпинальный", что оно значит?

Comment: Посиотрите, может, это наведёт на мысль: [Эпинальный принт](https://hmn.wiki/ru/Épinal_print).

Comment: И вот ещё: [Эпинальные картинки](http://www.li.ru/interface/pda/?jid=4431574&pid=179325202&redirected=1&page=0&backurl=/users/rozalina6/post179325202/).

Answer (score 2):

"Жан-Шарль Пеллерен /Jean-Charles Pellerin (1756-1836) родился и вырос в маленьком городке Эпиналь, (Лотарингия), где после смерти отца унаследовал его дело -- печатное ателье, которое издавало игральные карты.
…Пеллерен начинает печатать иллюстрированные листки с познавательными сюжетами для детей и взрослых на самые разные темы. Первоначаньно среди них преобладали сюжеты на тему истории Франции и в большинстве своем Французской Революции. Техника печати сначала была той же, что и при производстве игральных карт: деревянная гравюра, раскрашенная в несколько цветов с помощью трафарета.
Иллюстрированные листки Пеллерена, получившие название "эпинальские картинки" (Image d'Epinal), распространяли лоточники-книгоноши. Вскоре цветные картинки очень быстро завоевали успех. Тематика стала расширяться. Начали преобладать картинки для детей: познавательные, воспитательные, учебные, развлекательные. Самой большой любовью пользовались картинки-загадки (evinettes) и изображения, построенные на зрительных иллюзиях. Сейчас такие листки являются наиболее ценными коллекционными объектами среди эпиналей.
Дело Жана-Шарля Пеллерена продолжали также его сын, племянник и внук. Несмотря на то, что династия Пеллеренов прервалась, издательский дом под торговой маркой "Imagerie d'Epinal" существует по сей день и по прежнему расположен во французском городке Эпиналь".
https://nevsepic.com.ua/art-i-risovanaya-grafika/8089-epinalskaya-kartinka-xix-xxe-images-depinal-123-rabot.html

Comment: Но Возрождение было до Жан-Шарля Пеллерена.